# How to skip sending FIN request from JMeter?

Tags: java, sockets, http, network-programming, jmeter

I am trying to use JMeter to simulate an application bug where the client application does not send the FIN request after a HTTP request completes.

Is there a way to achieve this using JMeter or are there other easier ways to do this? The goal is to test a server side fix, so it is necessary to simulate not sending FIN at scale.

**EDIT:** More clarification... Looking at a client side packet trace, every HTTPS request completes the 3 way TCP handshake. However, the client is not sending the FIN request to close the connection. The result is many unclosed connections visible on the server. I would like to load test a server side fix using JMeter or any other tool. Is there a way to create a very high number of unclosed connections?

Comment: First, are you sure you have a problem to fix? This is normal behaviour with HTTP keepalive. The server will time-out idle connections.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you refer to the FIN message in the TCP protocol.
Whenever a connection is closed this TCP segment is sent. In JMeter, it is probably closing the connection after receiving the HTTP response from the server. If you are using HTTP Request sampler, to keep the connection open you have to check the "Use KeepAlive" checkbox.

Comment: According to the JMeter docs, using Keep-Alive will set the header and not call close. However, this will have the side-effect of limiting the number of connections that can appear on the server side.

Comment: Ideally I'm looking for a way to create a HTTP connection, then abandon it. This would maximize the number of connections on the server side, but minimize the number of connections on the load generator.

Comment: @user3038060 That doesn't make sense. Unless you are running multiple JMeters the number of connections at the server and the number of conenctions in the load generator are the same.

Comment: @user3038060 with Keep-alive you keep the TCP connection open and can send a new HTTP message. Are you trying to send regular HTTP POST or GET messages and receive a response? What do you mean by HTTP connection? Please clarify what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

What @user3038060 needs is a software that can generate lots of TCP connection to server and then forget the connection.  So from operating system's point of view, there are many connections from client PC to the server but client application doesn't do anything with the connection (neigther sending nor receiving).

Here is a simple perl program that can do this (you need to have perl installed). Just copy it to a file, say, conns.pl.

You can run it as

```
perl conns.pl <num_of_connections> <serverIp>
```

For example:

```
perl conns.pl  10000 10.11.1.1
```

It will try to set up 10,000 connections to the server 10.11.1.1.  You can exit the program by ctrl-C.

Hope it helps.

```
use IO::Socket;

my $sock;
my $host = $ARGV[1];
my $port = 80;
if (defined $ARGV[2]) {
    $port = $ARGV[2];
}

for ($i=0; $i<$ARGV[0]; $i++) {
  $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new( Proto    => 'tcp',
                                 PeerAddr => $host,
                                 PeerPort => $port,
                                 KeepAlive => 1
   ) || die "failed to setup outsock $@\n";
    print "created a connection $i\n";
}
<STDIN>; #wait for user to type ctrl-C
```